# Best way to simple frontend that stores data

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple page that shows 4 different divs, all with a `<h1>` title (or other tag that shows text) and a form (with 1 input text) and a submit button... so far so good.

My answer is simple: I am looking for a way that:

1. when the user inserts a text and submit the form, the `<h1>` title shows the text that the user wrote
2. the form disappear (or takes style `display:none`)
3. this will take effect even if I refresh the page or view page in a different computer (probably need to save the data in a DB)
4. restart this process from the beginning (even if I need to code again).

This is for a mini game to provide to users 4 different choices and, if the user A select option 1, the `<h1>` will show text something like `"User A was the first to choose this option. Please select a blank option"` and, after the 1st raw over (point 4 described above), restart all forms.

**NOTE:** I am not asking in the way to "please do the code for me". I also searching for a way to store data in `<php ?>` - finding [redbeanphp](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) project.
I am also a newbie in SQL (just started to study SQLi last month to android development). My question is **ONLY** to looking for the best way to do this and what I need.

Comment: "propably need to save the data in a DB" - correct.

Comment: Sounds like you get what you need. The data must be stored. Use a database. Or, if the data is in no way private and you are feeling a bit sloppy/lazy, a simple text file.

Comment: @dagon I did not realize how your comment will help me. but it's ok! :)

Comment: @user2537383 Thanks for your help. And yes, the data don't need to be private (I only need this for a day). I will search/study for that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the workflow:

1. When you click a button to submit the form JavaScript will send the form data to the server as an AJAX request and wait for a response from the server.
2. The PHP code on the server will read the data from the AJAX request and save it in a database and echo a success response along with the text to display.
3. Your JavaScript will receive this success message and hide form from the DOM and display the text in the header.
4. If you want the data to persist on the page on reload then you can save a flag in PHP session.  Sessions persist in until you close browser window.

4.1 Use another AJAX call remove the flag from the session and reload the content.

So, if you are good with HTML and CSS you need:

1. JavaScript, AJAX, a JavaScript library to make things easier such as JQuery.
2. A server side language such as PHP.
3. A database to persist data. There are many choices.  I am going to recommend MySQL just because there so many tutorials for it out there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So yep, it all looks OK. Just a point: **4. reloading the page:** I am looking for a way to store this properties (even after refreshing the page) and a _4.1_ option to get back the initial state.